# I need to print RMSE but don't know why error is coming

Tags: classification, feature-class, regression, reducers, results

[image]

I need to print root mean squared error (RMSE) but don't know why error is coming. Can any one share code how I can calculate RMSE?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please do not post pictures of your code, and it is helpful if you can specify what software you are using